# MVC2 Html.RadioButton - Is there a way to set the InnerHTML using HTML Helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, radio-button, html-helper

Perfectly normal radio buttons in HTML look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="1">First</input>
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="2">Second</input>
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="3">Third</input>
```

As far as I can see, there is no way to set the "InnerHTML" (to use a JavaScript term) in an HTML helper; something like:

```
<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.somename, 1, "First") %>
```

All of the examples I've seen create a separate label for each button, which could work, but really screws up the HTML. Can this be done, and if not, why?

Comment: Far from screwing up the HTML, labels are very helpful in terms of accessibility for all input controls, even radio buttons.

Comment: @Xhalent: I realize this is my personal opinion, but <input> text </input> seems far more useful, especially when using javascript to access the innerhtml.  There is a reason inputs have a text element.

Comment: @Xhalent: Well, I'm an ass - I did some further checking and in HTML there is no closing tag for the <input> element.  I'll shut up and make with the labels now.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML there is no closing tag for <input> elements.  A well-formed input element has no children.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own html helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, string innerHtml )
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
    var radioButton = string.Format( "<input type='radio' name='{0}' value='{1}'>{2}</input>", name, value, innerHtml );
    return MvcHtmlString.Create( radioButton );
}
```

Comment: I'm completely wrong - in HTML there is no closing tag for <input> elements.  Thanks for the HtmlHelper implementation, tho.